# Exclude blank values from csv file for JSON array in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have jsonarray as `[foodid1,foodid2,foodid3]` .The values of these are reading from a csv file

csv file content

```
foodid1,foodid2,foodid3
10,12,14
```

if I don't want to pass the value to foodid2, the JSON array is being passed as `[10,,14]`

Instead, I wanted it to be passed as `[10,14]`.

following is the JSON body:

```
    customerdetails={
    "regDate":${regDate},
    "regNo":"${regNo}",
    "firstName":"${fname}",
    "lastName":"${lname}",
    "dateOfBirth":"${dob}",
    "bloodGroupId":0,
    "mobileNo":"${mobile}",
    "residenceNo":"${resdno}",
    "officeNo":"${officeno}",
    "email":"${email}",
    "address1":"${adr1}",
    "address2":"${adr2}",
    "pincode":"${pin}",
    "stateId":${stateid},
    "city":"${city}"}
&customerhistory={
"historyId":[${food1},${food2},${food3},${food4}]}
```

how can I handle this situation in Jmeter

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try with BeanShell pre-processor and format the data as per your needs, store it in a variable and then use it in the request. can you please share the CSV DataSet Config and HTTP Sampler screenshots

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be replacing double commas with single commas on the fly using [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request you're going to modify
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;

   Arguments oldArgs = sampler.getArguments();
   Arguments newArgs = new Arguments();

   for (int i = 0; i < oldArgs.getArgumentCount(); i++) {
       Argument argument = oldArgs.getArgument(i);
       String oldValue = argument.getValue();
       String newValue = oldValue.replaceAll(",,", ",");
       newArgs.addArgument(new HTTPArgument(argument.getName(), newValue));
   }

   sampler.setArguments(newArgs);
   ```

   When you will run your test the PreProcessor will replace `,,` with `,` for each parameter value.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information about using Beanshell in JMeter tests.